# sql query to count records on a column which is in longtext

Tags: mysql, sql

table :

```
profile_data : id(int),age(int),gender(varchar),goals(longtext)
```

I want to write a query which will give the average number of goals set by each of the ids.

How do I count on it when its in a textual format?

I tried :

```
select id,avg(count(goals)) from profile_data;
```

Its showing query is incorrect.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Could you please show us what have you tried so far??

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: You need a `group by`

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do. Do you want a count by id? Because  "average number of goals set by each of the ids" doesn't make much sense; an id only has a single count of goals, so there is nothing to average (average = count).

Comment: @HoneyBadger no a user can have multiple goals, so I want to count the average number of goals per user

Comment: Yes a user can have multiple goals, but only one **count of goals**, so what do you want to average?

Comment: By the way, if a user can have multiple goals, what is the primary key in your table? It can't be Id if an id can have multiple goals. Do you perhaps want to count *within* the column `goals`? Is your data normalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you perhaps require something like this?

```
SELECT avg(cnt)
FROM   (
          SELECT id
          ,      count(goals) as cnt
          FROM   profile_data
          GROUP  BY id
       ) gr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY, go through aggregate functions of your DBMS

```
SELECT id
      ,avg(goals) 
FROM profile_data
GROUP BY id;
```